# highchart set data to series in xrange chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am creating a **xrange** highchart using this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/kmzzk0dg/2/) as reference.

How do I pass values to **"x","x2","y"** values from list?

For normal column/bar chart I would do the following and it works fine.

```
var percent=[98,100,95]; //data
series: [{
            name: 'Percent',
            data: percent,
        }]
```

like wise how to pass values to X-range series?
I tried the following but didn't work. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damseldeebi/omgg8Lpe/1/) here

```
var alphax = [1436824800000, 1436220000000]; //data for x
var alphax2 = [1438207200000, 1438120800000]; //data for x2
var alphay = [1, 0]; //data for y

series:[{
            name: 'Alpha',
            data: [ x= alphax, x2=alphax2, y= alphay ],
        }
```

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate over the list and push items in x,x2,y.

```
var alphax = [1436824800000, 1436220000000]; //data for x
var alphax2 = [1438207200000, 1438120800000]; //data for x2
var alphay = [1, 0];
var dataforRange= [];
for(var i=0;i<alphax.length;i++){
dataforRange.push({"x": alphax[i],
            "x2": alphax2[i],
            "y": alphay[i]});
}
```

See [Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/omgg8Lpe/2/)